# How to create and deploy custom policies on the resources of GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, cloud, policy, sentinel

I want to create organizational custom policies and apply those to different services of GCP.  The policies are mainly related to security which can actually be created using licensed Sentinel DSL language.

I want to know whether it's feasible to achieve the same without sentinel DSL.

- Is there any way to do it only with Terraform?
- Is it mandatory to use sentinel for policy creation?

Thanks!

Comment: By Sentinel you are referring to the Hashi enterprise software product?

Comment: @MattSchuchard yes